# Storing JSON response in a database won't work

Tags: mongodb, node.js

I have this NodeJS app which fetches JSON-type response from a web application and store that on a MongoDB.

Each time a result is fetched, it is logged in the console, and should be stored in the db:

```
var worker = setInterval(function(){
    var q = "some query";

    Feed.EventEmitter.once("feeds", function(feeds){

        console.log(JSON.stringify(feeds));

        store_feeds(JSON.stringify(feeds));
    });

    get_feeds(q);

    console.log("\nWorker is running...\n");

}, 5000);
```

However it can be logged in the console, it wont store in the database, although the `store_feeds` function works.

Comment: Can you show the stringified json string?

Comment: Its quite long, its like this: {
"completed_in":0.152,"max_id":13382999338503780"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON `{ "completed_in":0.152,"max_id":13382999338503780" }` is malformed.

This

```
{ "completed_in":0.152,"max_id":13382999338503780 }
```

or this

```
{ "completed_in":"0.152","max_id":"13382999338503780" }
```

would be correct.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake I typed it incorrectly. the JSON response is like this: { "completed_in":0.152,"max_id":13382999338503780 }